# Split an image into pieces

Tags: matlab, split, image-manipulation, tiff

I have a 128x1500 image that I need to split into pieces (matlab reads it as 1500x128).  But regardless of how columns or rows are oriented, it is a rectangle that's wider than it is tall.  I need to figure out how to just split it into 10 or so different pieces (all the same height).  The image is a .tiff so online programs that do this don't accept it.  I'm working in matlab right now, so if there's a way to do it there that'd be great, but any way to do it at all would be very helpful.

Comment: What output do you want? Do you want to inspect the fragments in matlab or save them to tiffs?

Comment: saving them to tiffs would be ideal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input = rand(1500,128,3); %read your .tiff here

N = 8;
h = 128/N;

img = cell(N,1);
for k = 1:N,
    img{k} = input(:,(k-1)*h+1:k*h,:);
end

imshow(img{3});
```

I used N=8 because you specified that you wanted "same height".

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different, starting from the directory containing your tif:

```
N = 150; % width of individual images, final size: N x 128 (x3)
img = imread(tif_file_name);
M = floor(size(img,1)/N);
img=mat2cell(img(1:M*N,:,:),N*ones(M,1),128,3);
for ii=1:length(img)
    imwrite(img{ii},['test' num2str(ii) '.tif'],'tif')
end
```

Set `N` once you decide on a desired output size and specify the filename in `tif_file_name`.

Comment: Note that a number `size(img,1) - N*M` of trailing columns in your image array are not saved, but this can be readily changed.